# ProcessItem when extending JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor

Tags: jss, layout-service

When extending **JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor**, is there a way to call ProcessItem just like in **Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.ContentsResolvers.RenderingContentsResolver**?

```
public class SampleContextExtension : Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Pipelines.GetLayoutServiceContext.JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor
   {
       public SampleContextExtension(IConfigurationResolver configurationResolver) : base(configurationResolver)
       {
       }

       protected override void DoProcess(GetLayoutServiceContextArgs args, AppConfiguration application)
       {
           var item = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(new ID("11112222-4444-5555-6666-3333AAAA2222"));
           // Use ProcessItems here?
           args.ContextData.Add("contextItems", ProcessItems(item.Children, rendering, renderingConfig));
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are extending the `JssGetLayoutServiceContextProcessor`, you will not have access to the `ProcessItems` method from the `RenderingContentsResolver`.

One thing you can do is to implement it within your `SampleContextExtension` class. The code for the ProcessItems is as follows:

```
protected virtual JArray ProcessItems(IEnumerable<Item> items, Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering rendering, IRenderingConfiguration renderingConfig)
{
  JArray jarray = new JArray();
  foreach (Item obj in items)
  {
    JObject jobject1 = this.ProcessItem(obj, rendering, renderingConfig);
    JObject jobject2 = new JObject()
    {
      ["id"] = (JToken) obj.ID.Guid.ToString(),
      ["name"] = (JToken) obj.Name,
      ["displayName"] = (JToken) obj.DisplayName,
      ["fields"] = (JToken) jobject1
    };
    jarray.Add((JToken) jobject2);
  }
  return jarray;
}

protected virtual JObject ProcessItem(Item item, Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering rendering, IRenderingConfiguration renderingConfig)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, nameof (item));
    using (new SettingsSwitcher("Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl", this.IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls.ToString()))
    {
        return JObject.Parse(renderingConfig.ItemSerializer.Serialize(item));
    }
}
```

So, from the `ProcessItems()`, it calls the `ProcessItem()` method

Note, you may also implement it in your own ways by creating an object for the properties `Id`, `Name`, `DisplayName`. It is only for the `fields` that uses the `ProcessItem` method